# percentage growth formula using excel

Tags: excel

I have a value in excel B2 (16229) and a value in C2 (30530) and trying to figure out the quickest way to find out what the percentage growth is. I tried B2/C2 but that is correct. I know I am trying to end up some where around 88.12% approx as my figure which equals the growth. ?

Comment: Try an internet search on "Excel Percentage Growth."

Answer (score 3):

To get growth, you take (current value - starting value) / (starting value).  For example, yours would be (30530 - 16229) / (16229) = 88.12%.  This would then be =(C2 - B2)/ B2

Answer (score 2):

Try "=C2/B2-1".

For more information, check the following link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214078

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare a new period to a base period and describe "change", you should always us the formula  `change = (new - base)/base` .  This allows you to say that the new value was the `base value + change*base`.

When trying to describe an improvement in, say time to accomplish something, one is often tempted to use `change = (base - new)/new` because it yields a "bigger" percentage which sounds better to brag about (particularly in marketing literature). However I would recommend always using the formula above.